# prototypal inheritance issue after adding event listener

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

How can I access the root `this` inside the `events` property of the `Test` object:

```
"use strict";

var Test = function (element, options) {


};

Test.prototype = {

    constructor: Test,

    events: {

        handleEvent: function (event) {

            // this.setup() should point to the Test.prototype.setup property
        },

        start: function (event) {


        }
    },

    setup: function () {


    }
};
```

After I use the following syntax to add an event listener to an element:

```
document.getElementById.addEventListener("touchmove", this.events, false);
```

Where `this.events` refers to the `Test` object. After I tested it, I have noticed that `this` in that case will be the `events` object. How can I tweak the code in such way to have the root object available inside the properties of the `events` object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to move the definition of either `events`, `handleEvent` or both into the constructor so you will be able to get the right scope to capture the `this`.
Here is an example..

```
function EO() {
    this.ev = {      // copy over `handleEvent` and then capture the `this`
        handleEvent: EO.prototype.ev.handleEvent.bind(this) // with bind
    };
};
EO.prototype = {
    ev: {
         handleEvent: function (e) {
             console.log(
                 e,                    // event
                 this,                 // check `this`
                 this.prototype.ev.bar // how to access other properties
             );},
         bar: 'hello!'
    }
}
// construct
var foo = new EO();
// listen
document.body.addEventListener('click', foo.ev);
```

Now cause some event and you'll see the correct `this`.
If you want to avoid having to access everything through `this.prototype`, I'd suggest you use a different name for one of the *Objects* or simply put `handleEvent` directly in your prototype and not in another *Object*.

Comment: I moved all the props of the `events` including `handleEvent` in the root of the `Test` object because I couldn't make this behave.